# Pymongo insert and query reference

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo-3.x

I have 2 table and I want to insert a reference to the first table into the second table. This is the table I want to reference, named `player`

```
self.db.insert('player',
        {'char_id': char_info.char_id,
         'name': char_info.name,
         }
```

I tried following the official docs and do this:

```
self.db.insert('admin', {'char_id': {'$ref' : 'player', 'char_id': char_id}})
```

However, when I try it I get his error `bson.errors.InvalidDocument: key '$ref' must not start with '$'`

They queries might look a bit odd but all they are customized they just defined like this `insert('table name', query)`

How do I properly do this and be able to expand `player`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the very same problem.. But I didn't find right answers for it. However, I was able to make it work using DBRef..

```
from bson.dbref import DBRef
ref=DBRef(collection='player',id=char_id)
self.db.insert('admin', {'char_id':ref})
```

This should work..

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your idea is that it the Id doesn't get recognized as an Id. THis is why you have to tell pyMongo, that it has to deal with it as a foreign Id. you can do that with ObjectId:

```
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId        

    table2 = db.table2
    table2_elem = {
        'player':  ObjectId('_idStringOfOPlayerElement')
    }
    table2.insert_one(table2_elem)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)